# SQS Message Size Exceeding 256 kB

Tags: java, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, zlib

I'm trying to send a json object (serialized as a string) into an SQS queue that triggers a lambda. The SQS message is exceeding the maximum 256 kB limit that SQS has. I was trying to gzip compress my message before sending it. Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
public static String compress(String str) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Original String Length : " + str.length());
        ByteArrayOutputStream obj=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
        gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        gzip.close();
        String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(obj.toByteArray());
        System.out.println("Compressed String length : " + base64Encoded.length());
        return base64Encoded;
    }
```

The lambda that this SQS queue triggers is a nodejs based lambda where I need to unzip and decode this message. Im trying to use the zlib library in nodejs to unzip and decode my message like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let msg = null
  event.Records.forEach(record => {
    let { body } = record;
    var buffer = zlib.inflateSync(new Buffer(body, 'base64')).toString();
    msg = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(buffer.toString(), undefined, 4)))
  });
}
```

I'm getting the following error on execution:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "incorrect header check",
    "code": "Z_DATA_ERROR",
    "errno": -3,
    "stack": [
        "Error: incorrect header check",
        "    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:180:17)",
        "    at processChunkSync (zlib.js:429:12)",
        "    at zlibBufferSync (zlib.js:166:12)",
        "    at Object.syncBufferWrapper [as unzipSync] (zlib.js:764:14)",
        "    at /var/task/index.js:12:19",
        "    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:10:17)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can approach this problem in a better way? Is there aa better way to compress the string in java? Is there a better way to decompress, decode and parse the json in nodejs?

Comment: Why not store the `String` into `S3` & then share the `URL` in the `SQS` message for `Lambda` to pickup? This is the best method if your message is going beyond the `256KB` as a safewall. No algorithm exists that can compress so much down 100% of the time. It is recommended that you do have a safe wall in production environment to mitigate the fact that some messages (10% lets say go beyond 256KB)

Answer (score 2):

256Kb for the message is huge, if you send millions messages like this, it will be extremely hard to process them all, think about replication that SQS has to do internally.

SQS is not a database and its not meant to store a lot of text.

I assume that you message contains a lot of business information in addition to some technical message identification parameters.

Usually this points on a wrong design of the system. So you can try the following:

1. Think about the storage for the content of the business information. It should not be SQS, it can be anything, Mongo, Postgres/MySQL whatever, Maybe ElasticSearch or even Redis in some cases. Since the application is on cloud, aws has many additional storage engines (S3, DynamoDB, aurora, etc).  So find the one that suits your use case the best. Probably S3 is the way to go if you only need a document by some key (path), but the decision is beyond the scope of this question.
2. The "sender" of the message will store the business related information in this storage, and will send a short message to SQS that will contain a pointer (url, foreign key, or application specific document id, whatever) on the document so that the receiver will be able to get that document from the storage once it gets the SQS message.

With this approach you don't need to zip anything, the messages will be short.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sending a gzip stream, and then trying to read a zlib stream. They are two different things. Either send gzip and receive gzip, or send zlib and receive zlib. E.g. `zlib.gunzipSync` on the receive side.